# nativescript uglify issue

Tags: nativescript

After I run

```
npm run build-android-bundle --uglify
```

the below message appears. Does anyone know about the below message?

```
C:\nativescript\mobile>npm run build-android-bundle --uglify
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build-android-bundle" "--uglify"

npm ERR! node v6.11.0

npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10

npm ERR! Invalid version: "1"

npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:

npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:

npm ERR!     C:\nativescript\mobile\npm-debug.log

=================================================================

0 info it worked if it ends with ok

1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'build-android-bundle',
1 verbose cli   '--uglify' ]

2 info using npm@3.10.10

3 info using node@v6.11.0

4 verbose stack Error: Invalid version: "1"
4 verbose stack     at Object.fixVersionField (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\normalize-package-data\lib\fixer.js:191:13)
4 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\normalize-package-data\lib\normalize.js:32:38
4 verbose stack     at Array.forEach (native)
4 verbose stack     at normalize (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\normalize-package-data\lib\normalize.js:31:15)
4 verbose stack     at final (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:349:5)
4 verbose stack     at then (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:124:5)
4 verbose stack     at ReadFileContext.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:295:20)
4 verbose stack     at ReadFileContext.callback (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:78:16)
4 verbose stack     at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:366:13)

5 verbose cwd C:\nativescript\mobile

6 error Windows_NT 6.1.7601

7 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build-android-bundle" "--uglify"

8 error node v6.11.0

9 error npm  v3.10.10

10 error Invalid version: "1"

11 error If you need help, you may report this error at:
11 error     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

12 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with the dependencies in the project package.json file. Could you verify whether all of them are up to date while following the below-attached sample:

```
{
  "description": "NativeScript Application",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
  "readme": "NativeScript Application",
  "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "org.nativescript.testNG"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~4.4.1",
    "@angular/common": "~4.4.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~4.4.1",
    "@angular/core": "~4.4.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~4.4.1",
    "@angular/http": "~4.4.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~4.4.1",
    "@angular/router": "~4.4.1",
    "nativescript-angular": "~4.4.0",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "~1.0.2",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "~5.4.2",
    "tns-core-modules": "~3.2.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~4.4.1",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "~1.6.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "~4.0.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "~3.0.0",
    "nativescript-css-loader": "~0.26.0",
    "nativescript-dev-typescript": "~0.5.0",
    "nativescript-dev-webpack": "^0.8.0",
    "nativescript-worker-loader": "~0.8.1",
    "raw-loader": "~0.5.1",
    "resolve-url-loader": "~2.1.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2",
    "webpack": "~3.2.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.8.2",
    "webpack-sources": "~1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "ns-bundle": "ns-bundle",
    "start-android-bundle": "npm run ns-bundle --android --run-app",
    "start-ios-bundle": "npm run ns-bundle --ios --run-app",
    "build-android-bundle": "npm run ns-bundle --android --build-app",
    "build-ios-bundle": "npm run ns-bundle --ios --build-app",
    "publish-ios-bundle": "npm run ns-bundle --ios --publish-app",
    "generate-android-snapshot": "generate-android-snapshot --targetArchs arm,arm64,ia32 --install"
  }
}
```

After that delete node_modules and platforms folders. Run `npm install` and try to rebuild the project with `npm run build-android-bundle --uglify`

If the problem still persists, please provide some more info about the issue and share your package.json file. It would help if you could provide some sample project, which could be debugged locally.